# Navigate Page to Page in Web Application Keeping user inputs

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible in an ASP.NET application to keep what the user has entered from one page to another, similar to a Windows Application? so when the user navigates back to the main page, all the info entered still remains.

Comment: Some more details about your specific app would help; is performance an issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of options (there are probably more):

1. Cookies.
2. Individual Session objects for the data you want to persist
3. Single Dictionary object stored in session that holds the question/answer pairs.
4. Round trip to the database each time and retrieve/store the answers based on some key.

I would personally choose option 3 (combined with saving to the DB when appropriate). The dictionary object is easy to work with and you limit the amount of useless crap floating around in Session and cluttering things up.

It really depends on your specific application, though. Some more details would be helpful.

Comment: So basically when you navigate back to a page after filling in some values, you'd have to repopulate the values from stored data in a session object?

Answer (score 1):

I think sessions are ideal here...